# On Android with root access, how can I get READ_CALL_LOG permission?

Tags: android, permissions, root

I should start by saying that this is a private app, so I don't need to worry about Google Play allowing my app to be published.

I have my app installed on the `system` partition, in the `priv-app` folder, and I'm already getting some privileged permissions, like `READ_VOICEMAIL` and `WRITE_VOICEMAIL`. However, I can't get the `READ_CALL_LOG` permission at all.

Are there any extra steps required to get that permission?

**Edit:** I should clarify that there is no problem with the code at any point. The permissions simply get rejected. As I menioned, I can request (and receive) other privileged permissions just fine. It is my understanding that this is happening because `READ_CALL_LOG` permission level is `dangerous`, and it normally gets "allowed" by the app installer. However, since my app is never technically installed (it's copied to the system partition in a Magisk module), I don't know how to grant it that permission level. I can also manually go into the app settings, and try to allow the Call Log permission there. However, it never actually "sticks". Again, no errors or messages of any kind -- it appears to let me allow access, but if I go right back into it, it's still denied.

**Update:** I think I have confirmation that it's happening because my root app was never "installed". Instead of installing it as a Magisk Module, I tried sideloading it as a regular APK, and when I did that, I was able to acquire the `READ_CALL_LOG` permission without any issues. But when I uninstalled it, and then put it back as a Magisk module, the same problem started happening. So, is there something else that I can do to make the system think that the app was actually "installed"?

Comment: How do you you don't get the permission? If you execute code that fails please include it in your post.